# PHP move_uploaded_file not writing to directory with all writing permissions

Tags: php, file-upload

I am in the process of teaching myself PHP, and am trying to create a function in PHP for uploading a file. However, move_uploaded_file refuses to work for me. Below is the function I can't get to work.

This function tests if the mimetype is correct, the filesize is not too big and the image dimensions. Then it creates a random name for the file, moves it to the correct folder and changes the path in the DB to the avatar.

```
   public function updateAvatar($avatar)
   {
    global $db; //PDO DB connection

    $available_mimes = array(
        'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'jpg' => 'image/jpg',
        'iejpg' => 'image/pjpeg'); // Define an array with allowed filetypes

    $image_info = getimagesize($avatar["tmp_name"]);
    $image_width = $image_info[0];
    $image_height = $image_info[1]; // Retrieve the image size

    //Test if the uploaded avatar has the desired type, file size and dimensions.
    if (in_array($avatar['type'], $available_mimes) && $avatar['size'] >= self::MAX_AVATAR_SIZE && $image_height <= 150 && $image_width <= 150)
    {
        $timeInSeconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
        $filename = md5($_SESSION['username'] . $timeInSeconds) . ".jpg"; //Create a random filename with the username and time in milliseconds hashed.

        if (move_uploaded_file($avatar['tmp_name'], "/Content/Avatar/" . $filename)) //Try to place the file in a folder
        {
            $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET avatar = :avatar WHERE id = :id");
            $result = $statement->execute(array('avatar' => "Content/Avatar/" . $filename,
                'id' => $_SESSION['id'])); //update filepath in DB
            return $result;
        } else
        {
            return false;
        }
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function move_uploaded_file always returns false. I have set the permissions on the folder to write permissions for everyone with FileZilla. It did not help. What am I doing wrong? Besides the hideous code that is.

Comment: Is `/Content/Avatar/` a path from the filesystem root? or from the webserver document root?

Comment: From the webserver root. The full path would be /var/www/Content/Avatar.

Comment: There's your answer then.... move_uploaded_file() wants a __filesystem__ path, so give it the full path

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. I thought the function worked from the webserver root. I'll leave the post up so other people can learn from my newbie mistakes.

Comment: If running the script from your root, you could have also used a relative path by removing the first `/` in `if(move_uploaded_file($avatar['tmp_name'], "/Content/Avatar/"` and made it as `if(move_uploaded_file($avatar['tmp_name'], "Content/Avatar/"` @Bas

Answer (score 0):

The function move_uploaded_file works with a path from root, not the webserver root. I forgot to include /var/www/ in the filepath.